# Bash on Windows 10 is not working

Tags: bash, windows-10, updates

I am planning to compile and run code in a linux environment. Before moving to a linux environment I want to try it out, virtual box and dual boot will take my memory. So, after updating my windows 10 anniversary updates, I was able to install bash (ubuntu) natively to my windows 10 through windows features. After installing bash when I try to run bash it's popping and closing a windows immediately. how can I solve this. I tried this with two pc, no luck. How can I solve this issue. Which registry file should I change ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turn your windows to developer mode, go to settings -> search for developer, then change to developer mode. Restart your pc. It should work now